# pandas.read_csv changes values on import

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks as so:

```
"3040",0.24948,-0.89496
"3041",0.25344,-0.89496
"3042",0.2574,-0.891
"3043",0.2574,-0.89496
"3044",0.26136,-0.89892
"3045",0.2574,-0.891
"3046",0.26532,-0.9108
"3047",0.27324,-0.9306
"3048",0.23424,-0.8910
```

This data is "reference" data intended to validate calculations run on other data. Reading the data in gives me this:

```
In [2]: test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, names=['lx', 'ly'])

In [3]: test
Out[3]: 
           lx       ly
3041  0.25344 -0.89496
3042  0.25740 -0.89100
3043  0.25740 -0.89496
3044  0.26136 -0.89892
3045  0.25740 -0.89100
3046  0.26532 -0.91080
3047  0.27324 -0.93060
3048  0.23424 -0.89100
```

Which looks as you might expect. Problem is, these values are not quite as they appear and comparisons with them don't work:

```
In [4]: test.loc[3042,'ly']
Out[4]: -0.8909999999999999
```

Why is it doing *that*? It seems to be specific to values in the csv that only have 3 places to the right of the decimal, at least so far:

```
In [5]: test.loc[3048,'ly']
Out[5]: -0.891
In [5]: test.loc[3048,'ly']
Out[5]: -0.891
In [6]: test.loc[3047,'ly']
Out[6]: -0.9306
In [7]: test.loc[3046,'ly']
Out[7]: -0.9108
```

I just want the exact values from the csv, not an interpretation. Ideas?

Update:

I set float_precision='round_trip' in the read_csv parameters and that seemed to fix it. [Document here.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-method-for-floating-point-conversion) What I don't understand is why by default the data is being changed as read in. This doesn't seem good for comparing data sets. Is there a better way to read in data for testing against other dataframes?

**Update with answer:**

Changing float_precision is what i went with, although I still don't understand how pandas can misrepresent the data in this way. I get a conversion happens on the import, but 0.891 should be 0.891.

For my comparison case rather than testing equivalence I went with something different:

```
# rather than
df1 == df2

# I tested as
(df1 / df2) - 1 > 1e-14
```

This works fine for my purposes.

Comment: quick comment on your `test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, names=['lx', 'ly'])` portion of code: The reason you are seeing your first output be 3041 is because names is giving you a header, then you are defining header=0 which is then using row 3040 as a header line (not counting in df). If you want 3040 as your first row take out `header=0`.

Comment: Thx for explaining. I had a specific reason for setting header=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparison purposes with other df's, you can use pd.option_context, (note I took off header=0 because it isn't displaying your first row in your df):

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.read_csv('./Desktop/dummy.csv', names=['lx', 'ly'])

test.dtypes

with pd.option_context('display.precision', 5):
    print(test.loc[3042,'ly'])
```

output:

```
-0.891
```

This isn't the nicest fix, but adding

```
float_precision='round_trip'
```

won't always fix your problem either:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.read_csv('./Desktop/dummy.csv', names=['lx', 'ly'], float_precision='round_trip')

test.dtypes

test.loc[3042,'ly']
```

output:

```
-0.89100000000000001
```

With display.precision, you will execute all blocks of code under this with statement at the precision you set, so you can guarantee that df's compared under this will be the value you expect.

Comment: Changing float_precsion='round_trip' does solve the problem, as does changing dtype=np.float32. Numpy must be imported as np for that to work though.

Answer (score 0):

it seems it is linked to data type you are loading, which is in your case float64. Using float 32 you get what you expect. So you can change the `dtype` while [loading](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, names=['lx', 'ly'], 
                   dtype={'ly': np.float32, 'ly': np.float32})
```

or afterward

```
print(type(test.loc[3042,'ly']))  # <class 'numpy.float64'>
test[['lx', 'ly']] = test[['lx', 'ly']].astype('float32')
print(test.loc[3042,'ly'])  # -0.891
```

Comment: well, it may depend on the Python and pandas version... could you also print what is the type of the particular cell? `type(test.loc[3042,'ly'])`

Comment: The type in the default is np.float64. Changing it to np.float32 does indeed work. I do find it interesting that the default interpretation of the data from the csv causes the initial problem though.